# Filter not null dates with Django and GraphQL

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

We have a tour node with `feauted_date` (`DateTime`) field, that can also be nullable.

```py
class TourFilter(OrderByMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = TourModel
        fields = {
            'featured_date': ['exact', 'lt', 'gt'],
        }

class TourNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TourModel
        filter_fields = TourFilter.Meta.fields
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

Currently we use `featured_date` for sorting with `OrderMixin`, but is there any way to filter them by not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`isnull`**-(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) lookup as

```
class TourFilter(OrderByMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = TourModel
        fields = {
            'featured_date': ['exact', 'lt', 'gt', 'isnull'],
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I've been looking for.